# Dll hell issue in .net core

Tags: .net, .net-core

There is open source exe developed in .net core 3.1.
I developed a new exe solution on .net 6 which gets loaded by this open source exe but the problem is with the dlls. Multiple version of dlls gets loaded  which I have checked using procmon but I get following error:

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0> System.Linq.Enumerable.DistinctBy(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, System.Func`2<!!0,!!1>)'

Open source exe loads multiple version and I don't how to force exe to load my project dlls which are latest version.
I have created opensource.dll.config with binding redirect but doesnot work.
How can I fix this. I want to use latest version of .net and I cannot modify open source exe

I tried putting exe.config and do binding redirect but didnot work.I copied open source exe into my folder so that dlls loads from my folder but didnot work